# Zmq REQ socket state after timeout (heartbeat)

Tags: java, timeout, zeromq

I'm basically doing this:

1. having a REQ socket, connect to a REP (heartbeat)
2. If connection times out (`setTimeOut`), increase a counter
3. If counter is bigger than a given threshold, mark the other side as DOWN (not heartbeating)
4. If the other side responds, reset counter.
5. Repeat

This has the problem that, when a timeout occurs, the next `send` method causes:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.zeromq.ZMQException: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state(0x9523dfb)
```

I'm not sure what to do, I've seen this somewhat solved with a `Poller` but it seems an overkill. What's the best approach here? recreate the socket? try a different strategy (PUSH-PULL maybe?).

Thank you.

Comment: What else do you need to know? Posting the whole code will make it harder to understand the problem, perhaps I can put a snippet?

Comment: Actually, it will be very helpful, but make sure they're snippets of the relevant parts only.

Comment: Tell me what part do you want to see and I'll gist that

Comment: The code for `REQ` and `REP` sockets config, connection, and message send/receive, at minimum, we don't need business logic.